# How to pass *args to map() function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, args

For example, a toy math function:

```
def F(x,*args):
    val=0
    for x_ in x:
        val += x_**2
    if val<=args[0]:
        val= -100
    elif val>args[1]:
        val= 100
    return val
```

I want to call it inside another function using map to evaluate a list of values:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def passf(F, x, *args):
        #do some operations......
        return map(F, x, *args)
    x = np.array([[0,1,2],[10,2,0],[0,0,0]])
    print(list(passf(F, x, 1,100)))
```

It gave an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. It works if `return map(F, x, *args)` is changed to list operation `return [F(x_, *args) for x_ in x]`. But i would like to use `map()`, since later i am planning to use `multiprocessing pool map` to evaluate the values in parallel. So is it possible to use map with `*args` as input parameter?

**Edit**: So this is the working main part, by using list operation instead of `map()`:

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def passf(F, x, *args):
        #do some operations......
        return [F(x_, *args) for x_ in x]        
    x = np.array([[0,1,2],[10,2,0],[0,0,0]])
    print(list(passf(F, x, 1,100)))
```

This outputs:

```
[5, 100, -100]
```

Basically `F` accepts 2D numpy array and positional arguments (*args), each element of the array (which is 1D array) will be evaluated by `F` and outputs a scalar. So in this case `[0,1,2]` as input will return `5`, `[10,2,0]` returns `100`, and `[0,0,0]` returns `-100`. So i want this to be done by using `map()` as stated above instead of list operation.
For `passf`, it accepts a function `F`, so i have many different `F`s which will be passed to `passf`, where each `F` accepts different `*args`.

**Edit 2**: added `F` as input parameter for `passf` and `passf` explanation.

Comment: `return map(F, x, args)` should work

Comment: @Sadap i tried your suggestion, however it gave different error `elif val>args[1]:

IndexError: tuple index out of range`. When i checked the value of `*args` inside `F` function, it only printed the first value of `*args` which is `1`.

Comment: Can you explain the F function? What are you trying to achieve with it? In your example, x is an array, with x[0] = [0, 1, 2] (in the F function, this is equal to x_). You cannot compare two numpy arrays as you are trying to do. It will lead to an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: It makes no sense to use `*args` here. Inside the function you are doing `args[0]` and `args[1]`. The point of `*args` is to allow **variable amount of arguments**. But you **ALWAYS** expect to have 2, so why not just do: `def F(x, arg1, arg2)`?. Also this is not a good use of `map`. Me personally, I would go with a simple `for` loop...

Comment: Lastly, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) takes **iterables** to be passed to the function (in `zip` style). So you want to duplicate the constant arguments for all calls. Something like: `map(F, x, itertools.repeat(args[0]), itertools.repeat(args[1]))`. This of course requires the import of [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat). But again this just loses the meaning of `rags`...

Comment: @agastya added more details regarding how `F` works.

Comment: @Tomerikoo i am aware of `itertools`, and i can use it to repeat the args elements each. However i have many different `F`s which takes different number of parameters. for example `F1(x, *args), *args=(a, b, c)` or even empty `*args` instead of `(a, b)` like my example. It will be very inconvenient and weird to create different `passf` for different `F`.

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of `passf` but anyway according to all that it seems like `map` is just not a good idea and a `for` will be better suited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since function F has two two (or more) inputs, you will have to use lambda to be able to use multiple inputs, then call map on that.

```
def passf_2(x, *args):
    return list(map(lambda x_: F(x_, *args), [x_ for x_ in x]))
```

You will still have to use list comprehension to break down your array into 1D arrays, but this function should work with your main aim of multiprocessing.

Comment: i was trying to understand it. So the trick is to pass `*args` directly to `F` by using `lambda`, while the `lambda` itself only accepts the array `x` as input. I tried to re-write your answer so i can understand it better: 
```t_F = lambda x_: F(x_, *args)
return map(t_F, x)```
works well too. That's a neat trick you got there.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Lambda is so that the function F can take in multiple arguments (map doesn't work well with *args or *kwargs)